# Django Models: Where is Model class?

Tags: python, django

On documentation it has been said that each model is a python subclass of `models.Model` class that is inside `django folder` followed by `db folder`. When i look inside my `django folder` i see a `db folder` which was `expected` and inside my db folder i see `models folder` which contains lot of files. But I was `expecting a models.py` package which contains `Model` class. So my doubt is from where does this models.Model class come from?

This might be not a top level question but I am hopeful someone here will certainly help.

Comment: from django.db import models, You have got to import it.

Comment: yes that works that is not the problem. problem is i should find a models.py package which contains Model class. I think that is what django.db.models.Model means. but it was not there so its like magic to me

Comment: Its defined here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L362

Comment: In `django.db.models.__init__.py`:`from django.db.models.base import Model`

Comment: ok now i see where the Model class belongs. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope it's not magic it's django , it does exist if you go to the django's source code, you can see that the [Model class exists](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/db/models/base.py#L323), But in that way don't you had to import models in this way??:

```
from django.db.models.base import Model
```

Yes you can do it in that way, But django does it for you in the [models/**__init__**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/db/models/__init__.py#L8) file, so the only thing you have to do is:

```
from django.db import models
```

models refers to the `models folder` inside `django.db` but when you import it, it brings you all the things that are inse the **models/____init__**.py file, I recommend you to read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)